# Emacs ESS indentation of parentheses after =

Tags: r, emacs, indentation, ess

How does one get proper indentation of parentheses after an "=" sign in ESS on Emacs?  As an example, I'd expect indentation to look like this for the "labels" parameter:

```
somevar <- factor(x = 1:3,
                  labels = c("a",
                             "b",
                             "c"))
```

Instead, I get:

```
somevar <- factor(x = 1:3,
                  labels = c("a",
                    "b",
                    "c"))
```

This only seems to happen if it's parentheses after the "=".  How do I get the desired behavior?  Am I missing some setting somewhere?

Comment: I was going to ask the same question.